# Issue with sqoop export with hive table partitioned by timestamp

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I'm unable to sqoop export a hive table that's partitioned by timestamp.

I have a hive table that's partitioned by timestamp. The hdfs path it creates contains spaces which I think is causing issues with sqoop.

fs -ls 
2013-01-28 16:31 /user/hive/warehouse/my_table/day=2013-01-28 00%3A00%3A00

The error on from sqoop export:

13/01/28 17:18:23 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:brandon (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /user/hive/warehouse/my_table/day=2012-10-29 00%3A00%3A00
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsUpdateTimes(FSNamesystem.java:1239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:44064)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:898)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1689)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1687)

If you do
fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/my_table/day=2013-01-28 00%3A00%3A00
ls: `/user/hive/warehouse/my_table/day=2013-01-28': No such file or directory
ls:`00%3A00%3A00': No such file or directory

It works if you add quotes:
brandon@prod-namenode-new:~$ fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/my_table/day="2013-01-28 00%3A00%3A00"
Found 114 items
-rw-r--r--   2 brandon supergroup       4845 2013-01-28 16:30 /user/hive/warehouse/my_table/day=2013-01-28%2000%253A00%253A00/000000_0
...

Comment: Can you share entire Sqoop command that you're using?

Answer (score 1):

You can try as "/user/hive/warehouse/my_table/day=2013-01-28*".

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is:

Select all the data from hive and write it to a directory in HDFS

(using **INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '..path..' select a.column_1, a.column_n FROM table a**) ,

and in the sqoop command specify the  directory location using **--export-dir ..dir..**

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Filenames with colon(:) are not supported as HDFS path as mention in these [jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-13) .But will work by converting it into Hex.But when sqoop is trying  to read that path again it is converting it to colon(:) hence it cant able to find that path.I suggest to remove time part from your directory name and try again.Hope this answer your question.